# Reading winword content in .net

Tags: .net, ms-word, office-interop

I need to read text starting with REQ_ anywhere across my word document. I have written following code:

var content = WordDocument.Content.Text;

Should I read all content line by line and then parse each line to check for such text? OR is there any inbuilt method similar to XML which would give me such text ? please click the below image for my winword content. I need to read the tags in red highlighted box:

[Programmatically fetch all tags in red highlight box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcPkc.png)

**Note:**   I have made use of inbuilt table object provided by word. Since my content will be part of tables only. See below code:

```
wordDoc.Tables.Count
```

//Loop through the rows and cells of this table and fetch the text:
 string currLine = aCell.Range.Text;

Answer (score 0):

Word has a built-in Find object that can be used to locate text strings in a document opened in the Word.Application.

Best would be for you to familiarize yourself with the capability in the user interface, then record a macro for the steps that work for your requirement. That will give you the basic syntax that can be transferred to your .NET code.

For more information, you can do a search on using Find in Word - there are tons of code samples out there, in various programming languages.

Comment: Thanks @Cindy. I have made use of inbuilt table object provided by word. Since my content will be part of tables only. See below code:  wordDoc.Tables.Count